# What is the best practice, to send data from razor page to contoller

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I need an advice, what is the best practice in terms of sending data from view (razor) to controller.
For example, here is simple form placed in the view:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Comments" asp-action="CreateComment">
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <input type="hidden" name="relatedPostId" value="@Model.ID" />
     <input type="hidden" name="username" value="@User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value" />
     <div class="form-group mt-2">
         <label for="note">Add a new comment:</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="commentContent" rows="2" required style="resize:none"></textarea>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Add</button>
</form>
```

And then, controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateComment(int relatedPostId, string username, 
string commentContent)
{
  (...)
}
```

The question is: Should i maybe use here some new "CreateCommentRequest" model (if yes, then how to use that, since in view which is displaying my form i am having totally different model), or maybe bind parameters in controller to some model, or maybe - just like im doing it right now, just pass the values to service from the controller, and service will take care of pushing a Comment model to repository?
Bonus question: Is that way of obtaining values from claims on the view ok?

Answer (score 0):

The way you obtain the claims is wrong. You should never read user claims from the client. The user can easily change the hidden input and submit a fake username.

Just get the claims directly in your controller.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateComment(int relatedPostId, string commentContent)
{
    // ...
    var username = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
}
```

For your first question, it is a matter of personal preference. One solution is to create two new classes, `CommentInputModel` and `CommentViewModel`. For example:

```cs
public class CommentInputModel
{
    public int RelatedPostId { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }
}

public class CommentViewModel : CommentInputModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Your controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateComment()
{
    // ...

    return View(new CommentViewModel
    {
        Post = new Post { PostId = 100 }
    });
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateComment(CommentInputModel model)
{
    // CommentInputModel has only the necessary information
}
```

And your view:

```
@model CommentViewModel

<form method="post" asp-controller="Comments" asp-action="CreateComment">
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <input asp-for="RelatedPostId" type="hidden" value="@Model.Post.PostId" />

     <div class="form-group mt-2">
         <label asp-for="CommentContent">Add a new comment:</label>
         <textarea asp-for="CommentContent" class="form-control" rows="2" required style="resize: none;"></textarea>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Add</button>
</form>
```

Finally, antiforgery token is automatically generated inside the form when you use the [form tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-form-tag-helper) so `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is redundant.

Comment: Ok, i see. And action will look like this, yes?:
CreateComment(CommentVm vm)
{
//do things with vm.CreateCommentRequest
}
Edit - and as i understood You correctly, this CreateCommentRequest in viewmodel, is (on page load) just an emtpy "template" to make adding comments available, yes?

Comment: Your action can accept just the `CreateCommentRequest`: `CreateComment(CreateCommentRequest request) { ... }`. And yes it's just an empty "template" so that you can use the tag helpers to bind inputs to the model, e.g: `<textarea asp-for="CreateCommentRequest.CommentContent"`></textarea>

Comment: Ok, im having a problem - with everything done like in Your sample code, i'm getting null/0 for all of the values inside the CreateCommentRequest object in my controller action parameters. What can be the problem?
I have updated my viewmodel to have CreateCommentRequest field etc. Maybe something is wrong with binding? But for now my form code is just a copy of Your code.

Comment: You were right, action has to be `CreateComment(CommentVm vm)` for model binding to work.

Comment: And is that fine in terms of patterns etc? Because in that controller action i don't really need whole viewmodel. But if its ok, and its commonly used practice, then its fine.